# Unable to log deletion of a line

Tags: python, set, compare, comparison, diff

I am currently working on a project in which I have to create a journaling file system where the addition of a new line and the deletion of an existing of a text file are logged within a journal in the Linux system. However, I am having issues with being able to log the deletion of a line. I am a newbie when it comes to coding so any help would be much appreciated! The code below shows a snippet of the def process_IN*_*MODIFY(self, event) method. I am using the pyinotify library.

```
with open(self.journal_files[file_path], "r") as f:
                   self.lines = f.readlines()
                   self.old_lines = self.lines.copy()
                  
               with open(self.journal_files[file_path], "a") as f:


                   # Check if any lines were added or removed
                   for i, line in enumerate(lines):
                       if i < len(lines) - 1:
                       #if len(lines) < len(self.previous_lines):
                           if line not in self.previous_lines and line.strip() != "":
                           # Check if the line was added
                               f.write(f"{current_time}, +, l{i+1}:{line}")
                           # Check if the line was removed
                           elif line not in self.previous_lines and len(lines) < len(self.previous_lines):
                               f.write(f"{current_time}, -, l{i+1}:{line}")
                       # if the line was in the previous lines
                       else:
                           # Check if the last line was removed
                           #if len(lines) <= len(self.previous_lines):


                           #if line not in self.previous_lines and line.strip() != "":
                           f.write(f"{current_time}, +, l{i+1}:{line}")




           # Remember the current lines for the next time the file is modified
           self.previous_lines = lines
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a line was removed, use the same code as checking if a line was added, but swap `lines` and `previous_lines`.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably replace all instances of "lines" with "self.lines" in the for loop that checks for added or removed lines. The rationale for that is "self.lines" is the variable that contains the lines of the file that were read and stored in memory, so it is the one that needs to be compared to "self.previous_lines" to check for changes.

You could also change the condition for checking if a line was removed to compare self.previous_lines to self.lines instead of len(lines) and len(self.previous_lines). Instead of comparing the lengths of "lines" and "self.previous_lines", it now compares the variables themselves. This is because comparing lengths alone doesn't necessarily indicate that a line was removed; it could also mean that a line was added, which changes the overall length of the file.

```
with open(self.journal_files[file_path], "r") as f:
    self.lines = f.readlines()
    self.old_lines = self.lines.copy()

with open(self.journal_files[file_path], "a") as f:
    # Check if any lines were added or removed
    for i, line in enumerate(self.lines):
        if i < len(self.lines) - 1:
            # Check if the line was added
            if line not in self.previous_lines and line.strip() != "":
                f.write(f"{current_time}, +, l{i+1}:{line}")
            # Check if the line was removed
            elif line not in self.lines and len(self.lines) < len(self.previous_lines):
                f.write(f"{current_time}, -, l{i+1}:{line}")
        else:
            # Check if the last line was removed
            if len(self.lines) < len(self.previous_lines):
                f.write(f"{current_time}, -, l{i+1}:{line}")

# Remember the current lines for the next time the file is modified
self.previous_lines = self.lines
```

Here are some things I thought would improve:
I added an else clause to the existing if statement that checks if a line has been added. This new else clause handles the case where a line has been removed, by checking if the line is not in self.lines (i.e., it was in self.previous_lines but has since been removed).

Inside this new else clause, I added a call to f.write() to write a log entry for the removed line. The log entry has the same format as the log entry for an added line, but with a - instead of a + to indicate that the line was removed.